# convert recursive function to use tail recursion

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

Say I have a function like this:

```
user=> (def m {10 5, 5 2, 2 1})
#'user/m
user=> (defn hierarchy [x] (when x (cons x (hierarchy (get m x)))))
#'user/hierarchy
user=> (hierarchy 10)
(10 5 2 1)
user=>
```

And obviously this is fine here because the stack depth will be small. But for this general type of problem, where I'm building a list that I want to return, the recursive call always ends up inside a cons call. How would I convert this to tail recursion, so that I can use recur and not take stack space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st variant

```
(defn hierarchy* [res x]
  (if-not x
    res
    (recur (conj res x) (get m x))))

(defn hierarchy [x]
  (hierarchy* [] x))
```

2nd

```
(defn hierarchy [x]
  (loop [res []
         next-x x]
    (if-not next-x
      res
      (recur (conj res next-x) (get m next-x)))))
```

Comment: For 1st implementation you don't need to define separated function `hierarchy*`. In Clojure it's possible to define different behavior for different number of arguments http://clojure.org/functional_programming.

Comment: marking this as correct. I appreciate all answers, but this comes the closest to what I was trying to understand (even if there are other, possibly better, ways of doing this in clojure).

Answer (score 3):

Read up on accumulators.

In Clojure this specific problem could be solved by using `lazy-seq`. `lazy-seq` defers the computation, so stack overflows are (usually) not an issue.

```
(defn hierarchy
  [x]
  (when x
    (lazy-seq
      (cons x (hierarchy (get m x))))))
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add that `lazy-seq` defers the computation of the recursive call until after the calling instance of the function exits, so the recursive calls actually never live on the same stack. "Holding onto the head" might still exhaust the memory but not because of a stack overflow.

Comment: You can still run into a stack overflow when you pile sequence on sequence on sequence. Example: `(loop [x (seq some-input) s nil]) (if s (recur (next x) (concat (do-stuff (first x)) s)) s))`. On realisation of the returned `s` you kick off a serious of realisations on the `concat` cascade, which can lead to a stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this elegantly without using recursion:

```
(defn hierarchy [x]
  (take-while identity (iterate m x)))
```

Comment: You can even get rid of the `partial` and use `m` directly.

Comment: thanks, I was wondering if there was a way to do it without explicit recursion.

Answer (score 1):

add `lazy-seq`:

```
(defn hierarchy [x] (when x (cons x (lazy-seq (hierarchy (get m x))))))
```